# Volume button events are delayed until after block is done

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This app lets the user take a picture, sends it to a server and retrieves a response. The letters are converted into vibrations that the user can feel with Apple's `CHHapticEngine`. I'm using a github library called `JPSVolumeButtonHandler` that listens for volume button presses and does something when it detects one. I want to cancel the vibrations when the user presses one of the volume buttons if the response happens to be too long. The problem is that when the app is playing the vibrations no volume button presses are being detected and so I can't cancel the vibrations. It is after the vibrations are done that the events are registered.
Once the presses are detected I can try to implement cancelation.

**Code in the ImagePicker gets executed after a response is retrieved.**

```
import SwiftUI
import JPSVolumeButtonHandler
import AVFoundation
import Corehaptics

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var hapticEngine: CHHapticEngine?
@State private var volumeHandler: JPSVolumeButtonHandler?
@State private var ohwow: String = ""
//other @State private variables

//other code

.sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerPresented, onDismiss: {
                
}) {
   
    ImagePicker(image: $capturedImage, onImageCapture: { imageData in
                    
        if let imageData = imageData{
                            
            uploadImage(imageData: imageData, serverURL: userInput) { result in
                                
                print("inside closure")

                switch result {
                    case .success(let responseString):
                    ohwow = extractedText(responseString) ?? "bad response"
                    ohwow = ohwow.lowercased()
                    print(ohwow.count)
                    vibro = true
                                    
                    viewModel.isConditionTrue = true
                            
                    finishedstring = morseOhwow(ohwow) //translates the string into morse code which is played through vibrations.
                            print("response:\"\(ohwow)\"")

                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                }   
            }         
        }
    })
}
```

**The Volume Button Handler**

```
VStack{
Text()
//Other stuff
}

.onAppear {
        
    setupHaptics()

    //setupHaptics()
    /*
    public func setupHaptics() {
        print("setupHaptics call")
            do {
                hapticEngine = try CHHapticEngine()
                try hapticEngine?.start()
            } catch {
                print("Error initializing haptic engine: \(error)")
            }
        }
    */
                
    observeCondition()
               
    volumeHandler = JPSVolumeButtonHandler(up: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{ //I don't think this is necessary but I added it for testing
                        
        if self.vibro{
            print("vibro is true")
        }

        else{
            isImagePickerPresented.toggle()
        }
                        
        print("DETECTED")
                       
        }
                    
    }, 
downBlock: {
    //Same as the upblock
    }
                  
})
                
volumeHandler?.start(true)
                
}
```

Functions for creating and playing haptics

```
public func createHapticPattern(_ doublenum: Double) -> CHHapticPattern {
        
    var events = [CHHapticEvent]()
     
    let event1 = CHHapticEvent(
        eventType: .hapticContinuous,
        parameters: [
            CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: 2.0),
            CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticSharpness, value: 0.1)
            ],
        relativeTime: 0.0,
        duration: doublenum
        )

    events.append(event1)
    let pattern = try! CHHapticPattern(events: events, parameters: [])
    return pattern
}
    

public func playHapticPattern(_ doublenum: Double) {
        
    guard let hapticEngine = hapticEngine else { return }
        
    do {
        let pattern = createHapticPattern(doublenum)
        let player = try hapticEngine.makePlayer(with: pattern)
        try player.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
    } 
    catch {
        print("Error playing haptic pattern: \(error)")
    }
}
    
    
public func makevibration(_ coolstring: String){
                        
    for i in 0...coolstring.count - 1{

        if coolstring[i] == "."{
            playHapticPattern(0.3)
                    
            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.6))
                     
                
        }
        else if coolstring[i] == "-"{
            playHapticPattern(0.9)
                    
            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1.2))
                    
        }
        else if coolstring[i] == "I"{ //this is for when a letter ends. Might be inefficient.
            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.9))
        }
        else if coolstring[i] == " "{
            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2.1))
        }
                
    }
            
}
```

I tried creating a boolean in the ImagePicker like in the code above so that instead of running a function inside imagepicker, it gets called by a different source when it detects a change. This doesn't work. I tried with Dispatch.global().async and Dispatch.main.async to see if it could work because CHHapticEngine has to be run in the main thread and in the jps library source file it also runs on the main thread. So maybe this is a problem to do with concurrency?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @burnsi The function definitions are now in the post!